# Remove Unobtrusive validation for Particular Control in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I have implemented one simple MVC3 application in which I have used **UnobtrusiveJavaScript**  validation. I have one drop-down in view which I don't want to validate it. event I have not put any validation in ViewModel.

ViewModel

```
public class TutorAddressViewModel
{

    public TutorAddressViewModel()
    {           
        AddressType = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    public List<SelectListItem> AddressType {get;set;}

    public byte TypeID { get; set; }

}
```

View

```
<table style="background: none; " class="addressDetail">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeID,Model.AddressType  , new { @Style = "Width:150px;" })
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

this Address Type dropdown I don't want to validate, when I have set  **UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled** this property false in web config it work fine means it not validate this control but when I have set it true it not allow me to POST the form when AddressType is empty.

So how can I remove the **UnobtrusiveJava** validation to particular control?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `UnobtrusiveJavaScript` to `false` in your web config will disable your unobtrusive validations globally.

If you are using `data annotations` then you can decide your validation flow like which property you want to validate. Because data annotations and unobtrusive js validations work side by side in this way.

so my advise for you would be use data annotations structure to validate your modal properties.

```
//do not put an attribute if you do not want to validate it!
public List<SelectListItem> AddressType {get;set;}

public byte TypeID { get; set; }
```

if you don't want unobtrusive validation to fire on certain property, then do not use data annotation attribute over its property like in your case.

Comment: i have not put any data annotation attribute to validate TypeID,still it validate because UnobtrusiveJavaScript set to True in web.config

Comment: cross check your code, or update your code to elaborate more, because unobtrusive validation will not fire for a modal property if you did not set an annotation attribute for it. your unobtrusive validations will not get in your way.

Comment: and can you please specify which type of error/validation result it gave you??